# .htaccess RewriteOptions Inherit is not inheriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I've been trying inerhiting my rules with **RewriteOptions Inerhit**, because for some reason rules are not inerhited by default.You might want to know that I'm on a *LiteSpeed* server.

The *IP* XXX.XX.XX.XX *points to a subdomain* which is *located in* `~/public_html/dir/sub/`

This .htaccess is located in **`~/public_html/`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX.XX.XX.XX$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

In **`~/public_html/dir/`** I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

And in **`~/public_html/dir/sub/`** the .htaccess also looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

*In this .htaccess there's also some WordPress code below which I also tried to remove but nothing changed.*

I also tried to use `RewriteOptions Inherit Before` but **rules from ~/public_html/ are not applied.** So if I go to the IP I'm not redirected.

Anyone faced such a problem before and got any tips for me what I cloud try? I really did a lot of search but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that inherited (in root folder) rules are parsed with the subdirectory context

```
/.htaccess
RewriteRule melon http://www.google.com [R,L]
RewriteRule /services/bar http://www.yahoo.com [R,L]

/services/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
deny from all

http://mydomin.com/services/bar => 403
http://mydomin.com/services/melon => google.com !!!
```

Maybe try with a more loose RewriteRule (.*)

Also, as RewriteRule context is lost, try using RewriteCond capture pattern if you need conditionnal rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/services/.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://elsewhere.com/%1 
#in place of a basic RewriteRule /services/(.*) http://elsewhere.com/$1
```